# How do i find the table index from stored procedure and access it from dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am Creating the adminregistration table, i get the 2 error  msg that i created in the SP the final Registered succesfully msg i am unable to achieve,  i changed the table index also. That's also not working.Please help me to get over the issue.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LoginRegister]
    @Fname varchar(50),
    @Email varchar(50),
    @Username nvarchar(50),
    @Password nvarchar(50)
    
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON; 
   Declare @ERROR varchar(100)
        --checking username not exist or not 
   if not exists(select * from AdminRegister where Username = @Username)
     BEGIN
     Insert into  AdminRegister(FName,Email,Username,Password) values (@Fname,@Email,@Username,@Password)
     SET @ERROR=@UserName+' has registered successfully.'
     select @ERROR as ERRORSuccess
     END
   ElSE 
      BEGIN
      SET @ERROR=@UserName + ' has already exists.'  
      select @ERROR as ERRORMsg
      END
END
```

```
protected void Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ValidateEmail();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("LoginRegister",con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtname.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtmail.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtusername.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(ds);
            
           
            con.Close();
            
            Lblmsg.Text= ds.Tables[1].Rows[0].Field<string>("ERRORMsg");
            String Result = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>("ERRORSuccess");
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('"+Result+"')</script>");
            Clear();

         }
```

Comment: If you want to send a (custom) error to the application layer, why are you `SELECT`ing a message, and not `THROW`ing it? Just `THROW` an error when an error occurs; there's no need for a `SELECT` statement stating "'Reistered successfully"; the lack of an error denotes success. (Also it's spelt registered.)

Comment: Also, it looks like you are planning to store plain text passwords. This is an *extremely* foolish endeavour. It leaves you and your users open to *huge* security risks. ***ALWAYS*** hash and salt passwords for something like this.

Comment: Why are you checking twice whether that user exists? When the first `if` condition fails, you *know* that the user exists, so no need to check again

Comment: Aside... [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). You should not be using [`AddWithValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue) and you're using it incorrectly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

AddWithValue, and the 2nd parameter can mess up, don't use it.

And do you really need a stored procedure?

And why use a dataset? Your stored procedure ONLY ever returns one table, so don't use a "set" of tables unless you actually are going to have a set of tables.

Also, you don't want to "manage" the closing of the connection, let the system do this for you. So, you do open the connection, but let the using block clean all that up for you.

Wrap such code in a using block, it will be taken care for you.

And do you really need that stored procedure?

I suggest something like this:

```
string sResult = "";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
{
    string strSQL = "select * from AdminRegister where Username = @Username";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL,con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtusername.Text;

        con.Open();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            // already exists
            sResult = "User already exists";
        }
        else
        {
            // does not exist, lets add it
            DataRow NewRow = dt.NewRow();
            NewRow["FName"] = txtname.Text;
            NewRow["@Email"] = txtmail.Text;
            NewRow["Username"] = txtusername.Text;
            NewRow["Password"] = txtPassword.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(NewRow);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            da.Update(dt);
            sResult = "User added";
        }
    }
}

Lblmsg.Text = sResult;
Response.Write("$<script>alert('{sResult}')</script>");
```